# How Garbage collector Will behave on value type and Reference type

Tags: c#, asp.net

How Garbage collector Will behave on value type and Reference type,  when it will free memory value type and reference type.  i am little bit confused about this can anyone explain about this, at the same time garbage collector remove free the Memory of value type or Reference type Which remove first

Comment: I believe you are asking question about Garbage Collector (GC), not Global Assembly Cache (GAC)

Comment: seems like you messed up GAC (global assembly cache) and GC (garbage collector)

Comment: Please look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342772/do-value-types-get-garbage-collected) from Mr Lippert

Comment: i understand what your saying but if both are there which one will gc will remove first..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You're thinking about the problem the wrong way. Stop thinking about "value types" and "reference types". Instead, start thinking about *variables*, and whether those variables are *short lived* or *long lived*.

**The purpose of the garbage collected heap is to reclaim the storage associated with long-lived variables.**  The purpose of the *stack* is to reclaim the storage associated with short-lived variables.

People will try to tell you that "value types go on the stack" and "references go on the heap" and so on, and this is confusing nonsense.  **Variables** go on the stack or the heap (or registers -- everyone forgets about registers) and variables can be of value type or reference type.

You keep asking "which will the garbage collector remove first?" That question cannot be answered. The garbage collected heap makes no guarantees whatsoever about the order in which memory is reclaimed. The short-lived storage -- the stack -- will be reclaimed as activation frames are popped off the stack. **However, the C# language permits the garbage collector to clean up storage that is referenced by short-lived storage before the frame is popped off the stack if the runtime can determine that the reference will not be accessed again.** Basically, *when storage is reclaimed is an implementation detail of the runtime, subject to change at any moment*.

Answer (score 2):

The garbage collector is concerned only with reference types.  It does not do anything whatsoever with value types.

Value types may live on the stack, in which case their memory is reclaimed when a method exits and the stack pointer is adjusted.  Value types may also live on the heap *as fields of reference types*.  In that case, the memory is reclaimed when the reference-type object is collected by the GC.

Comment: What about boxed value types?  Are they not cleaned up by the garbage collector?

Comment: @EricLippert ah, well, point taken.  I was thinking in terms of the model in the ECMA-335 spec, where "For every value type, the CTS defines a corresponding reference type called the boxed type" (section I.8.2.4), so I was including "boxed value types" as a subset of "reference types".  I realize this is not exactly the same treatment of value and reference types in the C# type system, but insomnia prevented me from making that clear.  Thanks for calling attention to it.