# TextBox + event with anonymous method, and Dispose

Tags: c#, winforms, events, garbage-collection

Sample code:

```
textBox.Click += (s, e) => { ... };
textBox.Dispose ();
textBox = null;
```

Will textBox be collected by GC?

Comment: It would be without `Dispose`ing it or setting it to `null`, too…

Comment: @minitech.  Does the event have to be removed from the textbox first? `textBox.Click -= (s, e) => { ... }`

Comment: @Harrison no, it doesn't

Comment: @Harrison: No, and it wouldn’t work like that (you’d need to keep a reference to the delegate)

Comment: It entirely depends on the code in the lambda expression.  It will tend to capture *this* (the Form object), perhaps the TextBox object.  If it hands these references to other code then you may well have a problem.  That isn't very common.

Comment: The code that you have shown is not a complete compilable example, so trying to analyze it isn't possible.  We can't know what the scope of the `textbox` identifier is, what it's content are (if any), where else those contents may be referenced, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be collected. Removing event handlers is only important when references to the *source* of the event are not removed. The text box is the source and you're nulling the reference, so it's fine.

You would have a problem if you did something like this:

```
parent.Add(textBox);
parent.Click += textBox.HandleParentClick;
parent.Remove(textBox);
```

The parent remains in scope here, so the event's reference to the textbox (via its handler) remains as well, even though the direct reference to the textbox through Add/Remove was removed.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, yes. When the GC decides to do so.

Comment: There really isn't enough information to provide such an answer, as per [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711285/textbox-event-with-anonymous-method-and-dispose#comment29282434_19711285).

Comment: Right, Servy. There really isn't enough information to know that the garbage collector eventually collects nullified objects... Except if it behaves as designed.

Comment: 1) We don't know if, at that point in time, the object that `textbox` used to referred to has references to it held elsewhere. 2) We don't even (technically) know it's type; it could be a value type for all we know. 3) The process can be torn down before the GC has collected an object, you can't ever say that something *will* be GCed, one can only really speak about when an object is *eligible for collection*.  It may be eligible when `textbox` is set to null, it may be eligible when the form it's added to is closed, it may be eligible when the application terminates, we can't know.

Comment: You know what, Servy? I'm taking a wild guess here... I'm thinking that... wait for it... textbox is a TextBox. Could that possibly be a reasonable assumption? Never mind. Next!

Comment: That's one *guess*, which is likely to be true, although you cannot be sure.  You also ignored all of the other points that I brought up, all of which are of much greater importance and are very likely to be relevant.  When you've responded to all of them then I can continue on to the other points that I didn't have enough characters to list earlier.

Comment: That's not a response to any of those points.  The fact that you have now dodged them twice would seem to indicate that you have no response to any of those other points, and that you yourself recognize that this answer is incorrect, misleading, and lacking in important detail.

Comment: I know, and it can be distracting, but hopefully you can get past my greatness for long enough to improve your answer, or address the points that I have brought up.  If you really can't do that, then at least delete it.

Comment: You really are funny. Please keep responding.

Comment: @Servy The answer is not incorrect. To your points: 1) and 3) This means any answer would be "misleading" unless full code is given and, by the same reasoning, the given answer would be useless to the asker (or any visitors) in any other project because the code would be different. For this site to have any value, we must make reasonable assumptions and give general answers.  2) Knowing the type [would not help the answer be more accurate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14043763/933416).

Comment: @nmclean Yes, as you said it's not possible to give a quality answer to this question without a full coded example.  *That is why the question should be closed*, there isn't enough information to provide a quality answer.  If/when the question is edited to have enough information to explain what's going on, it can be answered.  Knowing the type could very well be relevant.  I didn't say anything silly like "value types go on the stack", but whether the given type is a value type or not, in addition to the scope of the variable and what is done with it, affects what GC actions are happening.

Comment: @Servy 1) Again, if it's true that a full coded example is required for a useful answer, any answer's usefulness would be confined to a single use case. Your argument is unreasonable. 2) At face value, that the type "affects what GC actions are happening" is technically correct. But it is irrelevant to the understanding of garbage collection that was asked for. These "actions" are dependent on esoteric details, including CPU architecture. There's nothing wrong with asking for more information, but now you're only being pedantic.

Comment: @nmclean To not have a specific example would mean that the answer would need to describe the entire semantics of the GC to be complete.  Such a question would be too broad.  If someone wants to know how the GC works in entirety they should buy a book on the subject.  The alternative is an answer like this that doesn't teach anyone anything about anything, because there is no information in it at all.  No, understanding at least something about how value types and reference types interact isn't *irrelevant* to the GC.  If `textbox` is a local variable of a value type the GC is doing *nothing*.

Comment: @Servy You seem to be the only one here who cannot intuit that this is not a broad question that requires an exhaustively broad answer. We understand the basic concept the asker was struggling with and are able to provide a general answer that solved it. It is certainly more helpful than you posting outright falsehoods such as "the GC does nothing with value types".

Comment: @nmclean So far there generally seem to be several entirely different guesses as to what the OP is curious about.  To each person that guess seems obvious and intuitive, but the fact that several different people have come to vastly different "obvious" interpretations is what makes the question unclear.  I never said that the GC does nothing with value types, merely that it *sometimes* is doing nothing with them.  If it's a reference type we also need to know important facts like what else is referencing it, which affects when it can be collected.

Comment: @Servy: I'd love to watch you decide which cornflakes you'll eat in the morning. I bet you'll do an exhaustive and totally unnecessary analysis, or let someone else do it and then criticize it, and decide to eat a boiled egg instead. Oh well. Let's not sweat the small stuff and enjoy life.

Comment: @RoyDictus So what you're saying is that you don't *care* that the answer isn't correct, that it doesn't answer the question, and that it contains no useful information, rather than that none of those things are true?  If that's the case, why are you here?  If you don't think that providing quality and correct answers to programming questions is important (which is *fine*) then just don't.  If you are going to do so, then there is an expectation of quality.  If you are uninterested in when the GC is able to collect an object then don't answer a question asking about it.