# Performance of Linq query on large data set

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I'm running a method to transactionalize data stored in a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.  In CPU performance profiling, the major hit appears to be:

`foreach (Item inSequence in items.Where(w => w.SequenceNumber == i.SequenceNumber && w.Device == i.Device)) {}`

With 1,000 and 10,000 it is actually quite quick.  At 100,000 items the performance becomes critical - that specific `Linq` query goes from taking about 4.5% of the total runtime CPU to over 58% of the total runtime CPU.  I'm assuming the performance hit is specifically due to the size of the `ConcurrentQueue`, but I'm not sure what to do about it. If avoiding a Linq query resolved the issue, that would be fine.  I'm just stuck with what to do.  Is there some other concurrent type that would be more performant?

It's a CQ because the data is built and read asynchronously.  However, during this particular method, which happens after the data is built and prior to it being read back out, it's running on a single thread.

Very loose sample is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hjDOva

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    static int count = 100000;

    public static void Main()
    {
        var items = new ConcurrentQueue<Item>();
        var r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            items.Enqueue(new Item());
        }

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        foreach (Item i in items.DistinctBy(d => new { d.SequenceNumber, d.Device }))
            foreach (Item inSequence in items.Where(w => w.Device == i.Device && w.SequenceNumber == i.SequenceNumber))
            {

            }

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    #region Fields
    protected bool fixDates;
    protected string randomSerial;
    protected decimal amount;
    protected string device;
    protected DateTime depositTime;
    public int SequenceNumber = -1;
    [NonSerialized()]
    protected System.Random rnd = new Random(Int32.Parse(Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public bool FixDates
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fixDates;
        }

        set
        {
            this.fixDates = value;
        }
    }

    public string Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.amount.ToString();
        }

        set
        {
            this.amount = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
        }
    }

    public string RandomSerial
    {
        get { return randomSerial; }
        set { randomSerial = value; }
    }

    public string Device
    {
        get { return this.device; }
        set { this.device = value; }
    }

    public DateTime DepositTime
    {
        get { return this.depositTime; }
        set { this.depositTime = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public Item()
    {
        fixDates = false;
        RandomSerial = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 8);
        this.amount = 5.00m;
        this.device = "IC" + rnd.Next(6).ToString();
        this.depositTime = DateTime.Now;
        this.SequenceNumber = rnd.Next(10);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

However it doesn't offer the memory required for 100,000 items.

As to questions about using CQ, yes, I understand that queues are not ideal for this.  The tool generates data to test imports for various product types.  There's only a single product that requires the method where this falls, `Transactionalize()`.  Most of the time this code is not used.

It's a CQ because the system creates the objects in parallel (this was a significant performance improvement when it happened) and in most cases they are dequeued in parallel as well.

Comment: To be honest the architecture is flawed. You have a `ConcurrentQueue` which is a Thread-safe FIFO but then you want to filter it. You are meant to process the queue one-after-another fashion. If you want just any thread-safe collection use `ConcurrentDictionary` with your SequenceNumber and Device as `Key`. If you definitely have to have a partitioned FIFO, create one CQ per each SequenceNumber and Device. Otherwise what you're doing sort of defeats the purpose CQ was built for.

Comment: Please show us the entire set of code - ideally with a sample set of data that we can run ourselves. Please also include all object models. From your description I can imagine where there might be a few issues, but I can't give you an answer unless I see the full code.

Comment: im guessing its not the code you posted that is causing the problem, as much as it is what you are doing in the for loop or elsewhere. There is not much more anyone can say with this information apart from "*hrrm, sorry to hear that*"

Comment: @TheGeneral the profiler definitely narrows it down to the Linq query itself rather than the loop or anything in it.

Comment: mine works fine https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ds3Hbf

Comment: @Enigmativity I will try to put together a minimal code sample. I can’t provide a data set because the data is generated by the application during runtime - there is no external data. But as I mentioned, the profiler definitively points out the Linq query as the problem rather than the code inside the loop. It tags it even with smaller data sets, but considers it a minor nuisance. With larger data sets it flags it as a critical performance issue.

Comment: @JesseWilliams well what the others are saying is still valid - if your properties have overriden accessors than any kinds of ungodly whatever can happen. I've seen people create DB connections in accessors before...

Comment: @TheGeneral i think yours works coz in that sample you only access the CQ from one thread so any locking is minimal. I tried starting 100 `Task.Run()` in your sample to check it but turns out .net fiddle has an execution limit lol.

Comment: @zaitsman hah, yeah thats not going to happen :). However the example was to illustrate the point that a lot more information is needed. Which may include long discussions about appropriate data structures, models, what the actually profiler is saying, what we are comparing it to, the list goes on.

Comment: @TheGeneral i still think using CQ filtering is not super efficient if there are concurrent producers and consumers at scale of 100_000 items in the queue.

Comment: @zaitsman ok, that's fair. DB connections in an accessor would be pretty unfortunate.  I'm looking at what I can put together for a sample that still shows the issue.  The code, overall, is not exactly superb (I'm a QA guy, not an engineer), so I'm open to suggestions, but there's a lot of code at play so some form of minimalized snippet that exhibits the behavior will take me a short bit.

Comment: `ConcurrentQueue` is not optimised for that kind of code. Can you explain why you are filtering the queue like that?

Comment: If you really want to stick with those approach, use `var bob = items.ToList();` and then iterate over `bob` rather than use `items`. That way the cost of iterating over the queue is borne a single time, rather than repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the intention of the code below is to process the items in groups, with each group having the same `SequenceNumber` and `Device`,

```
foreach (Item i in items.DistinctBy(d => new { d.SequenceNumber, d.Device }))
    foreach (Item inSequence in items
        .Where(w => w.Device == i.Device && w.SequenceNumber == i.SequenceNumber))
    {

    }
```

...you can achieve the same thing much more efficiently by using the Linq method [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) like this:

```
var groups = items.GroupBy(i => (i.SequenceNumber, i.Device));
foreach (IGrouping<(string, string), Item> group in groups)
    foreach (Item inSequence in group)
    {

    }
```

Notice that instead of [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) I used the more lightweight [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)s as keys, that do not require garbage collection.

If you also want to be able to search for a specific group later, again very efficiently, instead of the `GroupBy` use the similar [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup).

Comment: Why do they "not require garbage collection"?

Comment: @Enigmativity because `ValueTuple`s are value types. They are not allocated in the heap (at least not individually).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias [value vs reference types have nothing to do with heap vs stack allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14043763/1541563).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I think that's a yeah-nah to use my local vernacular. Value types that are passed to method calls are placed on the stack, but when you have a class that uses a value type as fields or properties, for example the `System.Linq.Lookup<TKey,TElement>.Grouping` class, then the entire contents of the class are on the heap, along with the value types contained within.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I was afraid that someone would point out the related Eric Lippert's [blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2010/10/11/debunking-another-myth-about-value-types/). 

Comment: @Enigmativity correct. However there is a difference between cleaning up 100,000 tiny objects, and cleaning up a single huge object. The garbage collector is much happier in the second case. 

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Either way there is still one object to clean up. The result of calling `GroupBy` is a single `System.Linq.GroupedEnumerable<TSource,TKey,TElement>` instance regardless of the `TKey` type.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, in both cases the garbage collector will have some work to do. But by using value tuples instead of anonymous types as keys, the GC will have to clean up 100,000 fewer objects. Which is generally good, and for some types of applications (like games) highly desirable.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - If there are 100,000 keys then using a value type as the key might reduce the number of garbage collectable items from 200,000 to 100,000, but that doesn't mean that the using value types as keys you've eliminated the need for garbage collection. The way you've worded it in the answer is misleading, IMHO. Nevertheless, I'd rather have Eric Lippert weigh in here. He's the one that would know for sure what the compiler would do here.

Comment: @Enigmativity I would happily edit my answer with an improved wording. Could you suggest one?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - that was perfect, thank you.  The entire operation went from ~8:30 to ~1:30 in timing for the same data.  If you're curious, the comparison is: http://www.labyrintheer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/compare.png

I'm curious if anyone could elaborate on why my question was "bad". I seem to get that in SO (though not in SE sites), but inevitably someone gets what I'm asking and pulls through.  Thanks!

Comment: @JesseWilliams probably you were downvoted initially for not including directly the code in the question. External links are considered susceptible to becoming dead links, so including the code in the question is generally safer.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias makes sense, thanks. I will keep that in mind. Thank you again - your solution really did make an huge difference.